# vbscript internet explorer object ready state not accomplished

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, readystate

I apologize for my ignorance, but my fundamental understanding of scripting is quite limited to non existent.  Anyway, I have to go back to the mountain for some help so here is my problem.

I have a script I'm working on which will use 'for' statement to loop through about 500 websites.  On each website, it will extract data needed to loop through (nested 'for' statement) about 5 more websites to pull information I'm looking for.  Instead of making it to 500, it seems to get stuck at finding ready state after only about 6 of them.  I have changed the order of the 500 and it does not seem to be a particular website.  It also hasn't gotten stuck on the nested 'for' statement, despite running ~5x more times.  The procedures and sites are a little different as you will see.  The script just keeps grinding.  When I go to task manager and kill the iexplore.exe, the following message pops up when I run it through text pad.  Note, I highlightt the actual line item in the alarm text in the script.

Microsoft VBScript runtime error: The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable: 'ReadyState'

Any ideas here would be appreciated while i think more on it.

```
myVars_s = "~500,comma,separated,strings"
myVars = split(myVars_s,",")
num_myVars = UBound(myVars)

For m = 0 to num_myVars

     theURL = "www.website.prefix.com/" & myVars(m)

     set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
     ie.Navigate("http://" & theURL)
     Do until ie.ReadyState = 4         <---this is line called out by alarm text
         WScript.Sleep 100 
     Loop
     With ie.document
            set theTables = .all.tags("table")
            (find correct table and extract list of ~5 more strings = myStrings)

            myStrings_s = "~15,comma,separated,strings"
            myStrings = split(myStrings_s,",")
            num_myStrings = UBound(myStrings)

            For j = 0 to num_myStrings 
                myOtherURL = "www.anotherwebsite.prefix.com" & myStrings(j)

                set ie = createobject("internetexplorer.application")
                ie.navigate myOtherURL
                ie.visible = 1

                do until ie.readystate = 4
                    wscript.sleep 100
                loop

                text = ie.document.body.innerTEXT
                (use inStr(text) feature to extract the text I want)
                ie.quit
            Next

    ie.Quit
    End With

Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you run out of memory, can you check how many `iexplorer.exe` you have in task manager?
In some broken Windows System, your IE.Quit will fail...

also note the following points:

1. for outer loop and for inner loop 
   use different variable name for the IE object
   outer loop:  `ie` , inner loop: `ie2`
2. you used `ie.quit` inside the `with ie.document` block, might cause problem?
3. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046177/why-does-internetexplorer-object-become-unresponsive) post, you can try removing the `Sleep` statement inside the `Do` Loop

I would usually use

```
Do While IE.Busy
Loop
Do While IE.readyState <> 4
Loop
```

EDIT:

For IE.Quit NOT able to kill all iexplorer.exe, maybe due to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/03/09/opening-a-new-tab-may-launch-a-new-process-with-internet-explorer-8-0.aspx) reason,
To ensure there's no memory leakage, you can rearrange your code AND force kill all IE instance using method in Googling [VBA Kill IE](https://www.google.com/search?q=vba%20kill%20ie&oq=vba%20kill%20ie&aqs=chrome.0.59j57l3j60l2.2034&sugexp=chrome,mod=16&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

You should rearrange like this

```
for i = XXXX ' OUTER FOR LOOP
    set IE = 'outer URL
    with IE
        ' assgin the param. into variables
        start = IE. XXX
        end = IE.YYY  
    end with 
    IE.quit

    for j = start to end   ' INNER FOR LOOP
        set IE = ' inner url
        'loop inner IE
        with IE

        end with 
        IE.quit
    next j
next i
```

Comment: Larry, Good point w/ the ie naming.  My actual script does use different variable names (actually just by chance).  I changed them to simplify the question, good catch.

Comment: you might be on to something w/ the memory.  Sometimes the task manager only has 1 instance open, other times it can have a few extra.  There might be soem failure in closing it.  Any ideas on how to get around it?  Can I set a timer and then try to execute the quit and re-initiate ie again?

Comment: May I ask your OS and IE version?

Comment: I'm on win7 and ie8.  I tried commenting out the sleep just now, but looks like it hung up just now.

Comment: ok, i tried item 3, looks like it hung up again.  Is there a way to delete temporary files or casche of some sort

Comment: I usually Ctrl + Break  + stop to exit the program.  And please manually kill all the IExplorer.exe first. And please look into point 4.

Comment: sorry, I meant to say I tried do while statements.  I'm still trying to wrap my head around your next suggestion.  I will figure it out and let you know.

Comment: Sometimes Do While IE.Busy get stuck if your network is not stable.

Comment: Is there a way to call the 2nd for statement (w/ i's) from the 1st?  the number of i's will change for each outer URL.

Comment: `for i = start to end`

You should be able to get `start`, `end` from  `' assgin the param. into variables` part?

Comment: Yes, I can do that.  Maybe what I don't understand is the with statements.  What happened to the 1st for statement (within which I run the nested for).  I can research this one a bit and figure it out, no need to spend your time explaining basics to me.

Comment: updated my code snippet, the advantage is trying to keep only 1 IE instance at a time.

Comment: I'm sorry, these statements are actually joined at the hip.  It's going to take me a while to rewrite this.  Will update when I do.

Comment: Larry, I tested your sequence.  It seemed to show similar hang-up on ready state.  However, this time it hung up on nested for.  Based on your comments regarding ie.quit, it occurred to me that one common thread was very few operations between the ie.quit and same ie.navigate.  I added a 1s delay after quit... seems to work now, I cycled through 30 of these loops w/o issue.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MikeBb glad that you find out the solution, if you have time, can you try adding set IE= nothing after IE.quit instead of 1s delay?

Comment: I did try commenting out the delays and adding the ie=nothing after the quit.  It looks like it hangs up, similar to before.  I am able to cut the delay down to 0.5s, but haven't yet tried shortening it from there.  thanks!